# sql text functions oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function

They are 2 tables

**t_employee**

```
  ID             NUMBER,
  DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER,
  CHIEF_ID       NUMBER,
  NAME           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  SALARY         NUMBER,
  BIRTH_DATE     DATE,
  ADDRESS        VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  STATUS         VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

and

**t_department**

```
  ID    NUMBER,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
```

can you help? 
Display the employees whose salary is less than the length of address * 1000 and Rebuild column format ( surname name father_name) to format (name surname father_name )

1 part - Display the employees whose salary is less than the length of address * 1000 - is

```
select name from t_employee where t_employee.salary < LENGTH(ADDRESS)*1000;
```

but how change format text data???

column `NAME` from table `t_employee` has format

surname name father_name or (sometimes) surname.name.father_name

Many thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is surname or father_name ?

Comment: FULL NAME INCLUDE 3 WORDS:  NAME(Mike) SURNAME(Smith) and patronymic

Comment: or simple question:  column has format a b c - need select b a c. Which function need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
or simple question: column has format a b c - need select b a c. Which function need?
```

I guess you have to split the string using *Space* as the delimeter and then arrange the splitted parts. And I dont think there is a built in function for splitting the string. Instead you can create a UDF to get the work done. Use `substr` and `instr` functions for doing the same. If you need example code for splitting the string, use below link:

https://bitbucket.org/janihur/orasql-ex/src/8a68a1d724f1/split.sql

Comment: need substr and instr or REGEXP_REPLACE if it posible?

Comment: You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR also if you want. imo, REGEXP_REPLACE will not work here.

Comment: How to use REGEXP_SUBSTR here?

Comment: Please see Oracle documentation to know the syntax. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm

Comment: I saw already, not understand